# Why different HTML ids are having the same style?

Tags: php, html, css

I have two tables with different ids and they are in different page. Individually they are just fine, but when I include them in a single page styles are overlapping though the ids of HTML elements are different. Below is my code:

```
<head>

<rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
<table id="logo" style="width:100%">
    <th><img src="Image/vg_logo.png" style="width:150px;height:100px"></th>
</table>
</body>
```

Style for above code is:

```
#logo{
border: none;   
}
```

and another element code is:

```
    $query="select * from users order by id";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            echo '<table id="userTable"><tr><th>User ID</th><th>Full Name</th><th>User Name</th><th>User Role</th></tr>';

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['userFullName'].'</td><td>'.$row['userName'].'</td><td>'.$row['type'].'</td></tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
```

and style is:

```
#userTable{
float:right;
width: 550px;   
}
#userTable, th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:14px;
}

th{
background-color: #a1aec4;
}
```

Now the problem is whenever I include 1st page page with 2nd one, 1st table gets a border. Where I set the `border:none`, why is this happening?

Comment: Have you double-checked the validity of the output HTML?  That's usually a good place to start.  It's possible you reused an ID without realising it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line in your css:

```
#userTable, th, td{
```

to

```
#userTable, #userTable th, #userTable td{
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given  a global style to all`<th>` and `td` element be specific  with your selectors.. it is also adding a border to `th` elements that's why your #logo table seems to have border because you have one `th` element in it.

Answer (score -1):

@Mark is correct. Just for a note define

```
th{
background-color: #a1aec4;
}
```

also with a selector otherwise all th will get the same color.

Comment: Please don't use answers to leave comments